# How to divide an array into a bidimensional depending of user input?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm stuck in this university exercise for a week, I can't figure how to resolve it.

The exercise consist of an user writing words and storing on an array. Then, the user puts a number and the program divides the array of words into a bidimensional array depending on the user number input.

For example: The user writes `"Car", "Truck", "Motorbike", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird"`. And then puts `"3"`, so the program makes this:

`["Car", "Truck", "Motorbike", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird"]` to

```
[["Car", "Truck", "Motorbike"] ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird"]]
```

And if the user inputs `4`, the return must be:

```
[["Car", "Truck", "Motorbike", "Cat"] ["Dog", "Bird"]]
```

Edit: Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace probando_separar_arrays {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int num, i = 0;
            String pos;
            ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
            do {
                Console.Write("Please write a word: ");
                pos = Console.ReadLine();
                array.Add(pos);
            } while (!int.TryParse(pos, out num));
            Console.WriteLine("The input words are: ");
            while (i < array.Count - 1) {
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                i++;
            }
            /* Here is where I got stuck, cannot find a way to initialize the
             * Bidimensional array
             */
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? This seems pretty str8 forward. Post what you have tried (code) or precise question, not the whole task. After all, task is there for your practice not validation of someone else's solution ;)

Comment: Show us what you have.  It helps no one if we do your homework for you.  We can help, though.

Comment: You could use the linq methods skip() and take() to break the array into pieces.

Comment: actually, IF you are talking about a bidimensional array if the user inputs 4 it should be `[["Car", "Truck", "Motorbike", "Cat"] ["Dog", "Bird", null, null]]` It can only be `[["Car", "Truck", "Motorbike", "Cat"] ["Dog", "Bird"]]` if you are talking about a jagged array.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith you have reason, here's the code

Comment: Can't post code here, I'll try to edit the question 

Comment: Don't use ArrayList, unless you go back in time to before .Net 2.0 was introduced. Use a generic collecition instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Let user input all the items in one go, e.g.
// Car, Truck, Motorbike, Cat, Dog, Bird
string[] source = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// size of the line; 
// simplest approach (Parse); int.TryParse is a better choice
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// Let's create a jagged array with a help of modulo arithmetics:
//   source.Length / n + (source.Length % n == 0 ? 0 : 1) 
// we have "source.Length / n" complete lines and (possible) incomplete tail
string[][] result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, source.Length / n + (source.Length % n == 0 ? 0 : 1))
  .Select(index => source
     .Skip(n * index) // skip index lines (each n items long)
     .Take(n)         // take up to n items
     .ToArray())      // materialize as array 
  .ToArray();

// finally, let's join the jagged array (line by line) into a single string
string text = "[" + string.Join(" ", result
  .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(", ", line)}]")) + "]";

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Income:

```
Car, Truck, Motorbike, Cat, Dog, Bird
4
```

Outcome:

```
[[Car, Truck, Motorbike, Cat] [Dog, Bird]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic method that does what you want:

```
public static T[][] SplitArray<T>(T[] array, int size) {
    // calculate how long the resulting array should be.
    var finalArraySize = array.Length / size + 
        (array.Length % size == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    var finalArray = new T[finalArraySize][];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < finalArraySize ; i++) {
        // Skip the elements we already took and take new elements
        var subArray = array.Skip(i * size).Take(size).ToArray(); // Take actually will return the rest of the array instead of throwing an exception when we try to take more than the array's elements
        finalArray[i] = subArray;
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```